# Twilio autopilot doesnt say what it is supposed to say

Tags: twilio

I feel blocked here. I have written a Twilio autopilot task that is handling an incoming phone call. It is supposed to say  something, then transfer the controle of the call to a handler that will transfer the call to an external number. Here is the code:

```
{
    "actions": [
        {
            "say": "For this question, I will put you in contact with our customer care specialist."
        },
        {
            "handoff": {
                "channel": "voice",
                "uri": "https://handler.twilio.com/twiml/xxx-my hander id here-xxx"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

then the url of the handler goes to a twimlbin with this content :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
  <Dial>+32xxxxx</Dial>
</Response>
```

The problem is that the task is going directly to the "handoff" action and does not say the text. So the call is transfered to +32xxxxx immediately and the task does not say the text. I have tried to remove the handoff and then the task is saying what it is supposed to say. I really don't know what I am doing wrong. Anybody an idea ? 
thx in advance

Comment: I updated my answer below after talking to the team more.  It seems that redirect will also cause autopilot to ignore other actions in the task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio evangelist here.

So currently if you include the `handoff` action in a task, Autopilot ignores all other actions in the task and only executes the handoff.  To work around this in your case, you can put a  verb in the TwiMLBin you're handing off to before whatever other TwiML you have there now.

So simplify your Task:

```
{
  "actions": [
    {
      "handoff": {
            "channel": "voice",
            "uri": "https://handler.twilio.com/twiml/xxx-my hander id here-xxx"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

And in your TwiML Bin:

```
<Response>
    <Say>For this question, I will put you in contact with our customer care specialist.</Say>

    <!-- the rest of your TwiML -->

</Response>
```

The team knows this isn't ideal and its something they are looking at changing it.

Hope that helps.

Comment: yes it helps. thank you. Not the easiest way indeed but it works.

Comment: nb : are you sure the "redirect" will work ? redirect url is supposed to send back a Json containing the actions (to dynamically generate the actions). But here the TwiML Bin contains XML and also other commands that are not actions (like <Dial>. So it should be "handoff" instead, no ? anyway for my prototype, I used "handoff" (+put the <Say> in the TwiML Bin as you suggest) - and I confirm it works.

Comment: Yes, you are right.  Don't need the redirect if you are just putting the <Say> in your TwiML.  Updated the answer.

Comment: @DevinRader I'm having a strange issue where I'm using handoff - using the exact same Task syntax you've used above. I've then created a Twiml Bin and added a simple response like you have above. However when I try the assistant out in Twilio using "Test your assistant" I get the "application error has occurred" speech and the assistant ends the call.

Comment: @DevinRader I've raised a new stackoverflow question to see if anyone knows https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53205213/twilio-autopilot-handoff-action-is-not-working-with-twiml-bin